# Django Image in Admin Form

Tags: django, image, django-forms, django-admin

I want to attach and display an image in my django admin form. I have a model that gets used to create a matrix of fields that the user needs to understand how the mapping will work, and that is best described by using an image in the form.

I could do it in the frontend manually, but I want to keep it strictly in the admin. I can also overwride the admin form with a form that has custom widgets, but I'm not sure how to include an image from the sites static folder to get it into the admin form.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Buttons

class BTNForm(forms.ModelForm):
    custom_widget = forms.TypedChoiceField(
    choices = ((1, "Yes"), (0, "No")),
    coerce = lambda x: bool(int(x)),
    widget = forms.RadioSelect,
    initial = '1',
    required = True,)

    class Meta:
        model = Buttons

class ButtonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = BTNForm
```

How to go about it?

Comment: I think that better option would be to apply this logic from frontend.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to do it and you are using ModelForm you can pass it as helptext. Simply add to your meta, under correct fieldname:

```
help_texts = {
                'FieldName': ('<img src="X"  height="XXX"/>'),
        }
```